How to avoid disturbing idle state when sending a key by a script?
I have a script that is supposed to send hotkey to the system depending on a certain idle time. It looks like following:
SetTimer(doCheck,100)
sent
doCheck() {
 if A_IdleTime > 200 {
  Send("+{PrintScreen}")
 } 
 if A_IdleTime > 600 {
  Send("#!K")
}

Problem is, that when the keypress is sent, the idle time resets to 0 so the second conditional statement never executes.
I have some ideas in mind, but perhaps there is a simple and elegant solution for this?
